# How to read and listen for changes in firebase realtime database

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to listen for changes inside an `Object` in firebase realtime database. When I run the code, it prints the values right and once, but when I try to change, add or remove a value inside this Object, the listen function seems to be triggered more than once. When I try to monitor what is happening in firebase, it looks like when I try to add a value, it creates multiple values at first, then removes all of them but one. This seems to be the problem, Does someone know what can be done?

```
previousReadingsRef.onValue.listen((event) {
      previousReadings = event.snapshot.children
          .where((element) => element.key.toString().contains("2022"));
      for (var x in previousReadings) {
        print(x.key);
      }
    });
```